# the redo of undo when Oracle flushes uncommitted data in SGA to disk

Tags: oracle, background-process

DBWn is responsible for writing dirty blocks to disk when there is no more buffers or when this is a checkpoints. So when I updated my data and have not committed, DBW is signaled to flush buffers to disk. Before DBW can flush dirty blocks, LGWR will be signaled to flush redo log buffer to online redo log.

My question is: What's the content of the redo log buffer would be flushed in my setting ? Is it the redo for undo ? I don't know how this redo could be used in the instance recovery if the instance crashes at this point of time.

Thanks.

Comment: related question with an answer to your question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33687937/oracle-why-oracle-create-a-redo-change-vector-describing-the-change-to-the-undo

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are confusing redo with undo - the two are not the same thing.

When you issue some sort of DML statement (insert, update, ect) this statement is recorded as part of the redo log. This is kept in case something happens before this change can be written to the actual data files. When DBW runs it records the system change number (SCN) and that is how Oracle know the redo information is no longer needed.

Undo information is recorded in the undo tablespace (formerly rollback although there are some technical differences). This is only used in two cases - you do not commit your transaction or there is a system failure. The first case is fairly self-explanatory. In the second case Oracle will first perform a roll forward by "redoing" the statement in the redo log (starting with the last successful SCN), then performing a rollback by "undoing" any non-committed data in the undo tablespace. This will get the instance back to the last good state.

This may be somewhat simplified but I hope it answers your question.

Comment: I am not confusing redo and undo. Redo is used to roll forward, undo is used to rollback. undo also protected by redo.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question. The redo logs contain redo data, period. I don't know what "redo for undo" means.

Comment: "redo for undo" means the redo generates when blocks of undo get updated.